# How to delete the only cell from UICollectionView with animation (deleteItemsAtIndexPaths)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm getting an assertion while deleting a single `UICollecitonViewCell` from `UICollectionView`.

Precondition: I have a single cell (when I have two or more cells, the deletion works good).

Here is the code:

```
    NSIndexPath *ip = [_photosCollectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    [_datasource removeItemAtIndex:ip.item];

    [_photosCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[ip]]; // the assertion is raised
```

Here is the assertion text:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException: attempt to delete item 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 items before the update
```

Quite strange issue, because it works for 2, 3 or more cells, but when I delete a single cell, it fails.

Any ideas what's wrong, how to work-around this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to similar questions and answers on SO, found a solution to use `performBatchUpdates`:

```
[_photosCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^ {
    [_datasource removeItemAtIndex:ip.item];
    [_photosCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[ip]]; // no assertion now
} completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 13):

Same solution with Swift 4.1

```
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({            
        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at:[indexPath])
    }, completion:nil)
```

Comment: When answering questions, please don't just post code. It's important to explain why it works and/or how it solves the OP's problem :)